# Would "what are problems with my website's design" be an appropriate question for SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

Is a site critique appropriate for SO?  What about a focused subset of a critique (e.g. how can I simply refactor my color scheme?)
If not, if y'all have any suggestions for other sites to go to for good website critique, that'd be a nice alternative.

Comment: SO is for programmers... if it is javascript related - sure, but really HTML or CSS related questions belong on doctype like Shog9 already said

Comment: Markup vs. a programming language.  Sure, I guess so.

Comment: @Roboto: i'd disagree about html/css. they aren't programming per se, but they are code, and they are code that a lot of programmers spend a lot of time working on. i'm going to continue using stackoverflow for html/css questions as long as i continue getting great answers for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's appropriate, because in a lot of cases it's really just someone saying "hey everybody read my blog that you don't care about!"

Now, if there are questions about particular design decisions, you could post screenshots with generic content, along with an explanation and simplified markup, and I think people would be fine with it. Don't make people follow a link to a site they've never heard of that could be spam or a virus or who knows what.

**Edit**: Maybe saying that it's *never* appropriate is a bit draconian. I have seen a few cases where it was okay where someone basically says "I'm having this problem on a site and I've tried X and Y and Z and here is the code but I can't seem to reproduce it in a small bit of code--only on the live website. Can anyone take a look? the page is blahblah.com/testpage.html and the problem is with the option boxes halfway down."  In other words, they showed that they tried their best to produce a code sample but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't think that we (HUMONZ) can coral ourselves just because we might appear to be spammers?  I shouldn't have to live my life (on the internet) in fear of terrorism (spamming).  Otherwise the terrorists (spammers) have already won.  
That part aside, the idea of parceling the problem into small, bitable problems that work for SO, and just assisting at the solutions with accompanying screenshots.

Comment: ***coral -> corral

Comment: @Tchalvak: well, like it or not, people are going to be more willing to help if they don't have to follow a link to a site they've never heard of and look at hundreds of lines of page source to find the relevant snippet the author could have pulled out and put on the page.

Comment: good points though, my original answer was a little too draconian. i've added another paragraph of qualifications.

Answer (score 7):

How 'bout [doctype](http://doctype.com/)?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried using doctype some, it's just pretty ineffective.  Unlike SO, you post a question and get a single answer with about 5 words in it.  The difference in usefulness is pretty striking.

Comment: Mainly due to the difference in exposure, it seems.

Comment: The problem with Doctype is the users.